# @Query not working Spring Data JDBC 1.0.0.M3

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jdbc

In my Spring Boot Project, I get the following error when I add an `@Query` method in my CrudRepository

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You have defined query method in the repository but you don't have any query lookup strategy defined. The infrastructure apparently does not support query methods!
```

Libraries used:

- Spring Data Commons - 2.0.7.RELEASE
- Spring Data JDBC - 1.0.0.M3
- Spring Boot - 2.0.3.RELEASE

=== Updating with code

Here is the repository file

```
package org.docsy.app.account;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.query.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

interface TeamRepository extends CrudRepository<Team, Long>{

  @Query("Select * from account where teamId = :teamId")
  List<Account> getTeamAccounts(@Param("teamId") Long teamId);

}
```

I'm following the example here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/blob/master/jdbc/basics/src/main/java/example/springdata/jdbc/basics/aggregate/LegoSetRepository.java

==== Updating with stack trace

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'teamRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: You have defined query method in the repository but you don't have any query lookup strategy defined. The infrastructure apparently does not support query methods!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1708) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:581) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:741) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.docsy.app.Application.main(Application.java:11) [main/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You have defined query method in the repository but you don't have any query lookup strategy defined. The infrastructure apparently does not support query methods!
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:532) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:317) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$3(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:287) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:141) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:63) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:290) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.support.JdbcRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JdbcRepositoryFactoryBean.java:116) ~[spring-data-jdbc-1.0.0.M3.jar:1.0.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1767) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1704) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Can you copy paste somde code ?

Comment: Are you using the `@Query` annotation of Spring Data JDBC? As opposed that from JPA?

Comment: @wargre updated with code

Comment: @JensSchauder yes using the annotation from spring data

Comment: Could you add the full stack trace, please?

Comment: @JensSchauder updated with stack trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like [DATAJDBC-228](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJDBC-228)

Almost quoting (with generalized version information):

> The root cause of the problem is that current GA releases of Spring Boot specify the version of Spring Data Commons as 2.0.x
>   But the version of Spring Data JDBC requires 2.1.x which also gets pulled in automatically by Maven when Boot is **not** present.
>
> To fix this just add an explicit dependency to your pom:
>
> ```
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
>   <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
>   <version>2.1.x</version>
> </dependency>
> ```
>
> You might also want to look into this article about how to control versions of dependencies with Spring Boot: https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/13/overriding-dependency-versions-with-spring-boot

Comment: Thanks Jens, this did it.

Comment: If the answer solved your problem please accept it (and if it was helpful upvote it) so others see the question is answered and find the correct/good answers quickly.

Answer (score -1):

Try updating the Spring Data JDBC to latest version

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jdbc-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jdbc-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: That is a dependency for the Spring Data JDBC Extension. The question is about Spring Data JDBC. Different thing. Although the latter reused some of the URLs.